# Triggering spark jobs with REST

Tags: rest, apache-spark, spring-batch, job-scheduling, spring-data-hadoop

I have been of late trying out [apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/). My question is more specific to trigger spark jobs. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973112/what-is-spark-job) I had posted question on understanding spark jobs. After getting dirty on jobs I moved on to my requirement.

I have a REST end point where I expose API to trigger Jobs, I have used Spring4.0 for Rest Implementation. Now going ahead I thought of implementing Jobs as Service in Spring where I would submit Job programmatically, meaning when the endpoint is triggered, with given parameters I would trigger the job.
I have now few design options.

- Similar to the below written job, I need to maintain several Jobs called by a Abstract Class may be `JobScheduler` .

  ```
   /*Can this Code be abstracted from the application and written as 
    as a seperate job. Because my understanding is that the 
   Application code itself has to have the addJars embedded 
   which internally  sparkContext takes care.*/

   SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setJars(
   new String[] { "/path/to/jar/submit/cluster" })
   .setMaster("/url/of/master/node");
    sparkConf.setSparkHome("/path/to/spark/");

          sparkConf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR");
          JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
          sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "test");

      // Application with Algorithm , transformations
  ```
- extending above point have multiple versions of jobs handled by service.
- Or else use an Spark Job Server to do this.

Firstly, I would like to know what is the best solution in this case, execution wise and also scaling wise.

**Note** : I am using a standalone cluster from spark.
kindly help.

Comment: I added the Spring for Apache Hadoop tag to this question.  Spring Batch Admin provides a REST API for managing and launching jobs and I believe Spring for Apache Hadoop provides the ability to launch Spark jobs from Spring Batch...

Comment: @MichaelMinella : thank you for the suggestion, I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the Spark JobServer
https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

There are a lot of things to consider with making a service, and the Spark JobServer has most of them covered already.  If you find things that aren't good enough, it should be easy to make a request and add code to their system rather than reinventing it from scratch

Comment: Also consider before using Spark Job Server  - it doesn't support Spark newer than 2.0. Moreover, looking at their commit history - it's not super active

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk it's more active than apache livy though.

Comment: Spark Job Server has supported Spark 2.2 for a while, now.

Answer (score 27):

It turns out Spark has a hidden REST API to submit a job, check status and kill.

Check out full example here: http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api

Comment: Sounds really interesting, found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12696651/stable-spark-submit-in-standalone-mode-2-4-15.pdf so its means spark itself has now exposed this feature?

Comment: Afaik they have added it from v1.4. But they are not yet publicly promoting yet.

Comment: @ArturMkrtchyan relly interesting option, thank you! What happens if I will submit two applications simultaneously through Spark REST API?

Comment: The webpage you have linked does not really tell anything because pictures on the page are dead.

Comment: This one might help while the main link provided has broken pictures: https://gist.github.com/arturmkrtchyan/5d8559b2911ac951d34a

Comment: does it launch a spark session/context every-time there is a call to the rest api, or it uses the same session ?

Answer (score 5):

[Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy) is an open source REST interface for interacting with Apache Spark from anywhere. It supports executing snippets of code or programs in a Spark context that runs locally or in Apache Hadoop YARN.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19157438)

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer giving a little bit more details. Thanks.

Comment: Livy release cycle is weird. They release almost like once a year!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good client that you might find helpful: https://github.com/ywilkof/spark-jobs-rest-client

Edit: this answer was given in 2015. There are options like Livy available now.

Comment: don't you know whether it's possible to laucnh two applications simulateneously through that client?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The client is just a wrapper around HTTP calls to your spark master.  So if your setup can handle that then it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had this requirement I could do it using Livy Server, as one of the contributor Josemy mentioned. Following are the steps I took, hope it helps somebody:

```
Download livy zip from https://livy.apache.org/download/
Follow instructions:  https://livy.apache.org/get-started/


Upload the zip to a client.
Unzip the file
Check for the following two parameters if doesn't exists, create with right path
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop

Enable 8998 port on the client

Update $LIVY_HOME/conf/livy.conf with master details any other stuff needed
Note: Template are there in $LIVY_HOME/conf
Eg. livy.file.local-dir-whitelist = /home/folder-where-the-jar-will-be-kept/


Run the server
$LIVY_HOME/bin/livy-server start

Stop the server
$LIVY_HOME/bin/livy-server stop

UI: <client-ip>:8998/ui/

Submitting job:POST : http://<your client ip goes here>:8998/batches
{
  "className" :  "<ur class name will come here with package name>",
  "file"  : "your jar location",
  "args" : ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3" ]

}
```