# How to create Spark long running context from REST API?

Tags: apache-spark

We have REST services running on http server and would want to submit spark code/statements concurrently to an existing running spark application.

How can we create a long running spark context to submit multiple queries?

Comment: Hi, just to clarify. If I understand well, you want to do a `spark-submit` once that will be alive infinitely and submit here the queries to execute ?  Or you want literally reload the deployed JAR for an already running application?

Comment: No, I am able to do spark-submit once using sparkLauncher but what i need is something like spark-jobserver, where we can submit a piece of spark code snippet and gets u the data...i am exploring that now. https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use the project before so I'm wondering what's the difference with a notebook? I ask because on this https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/admin-guide/spark-admin/spark-job-server.html#understanding-the-spark-job-server page they say that the "Qubole’s Spark Job Server is backed by Apache Zeppelin". And maybe using a notebook will be easier?

Comment: You can use Apache-Livy or Spark JobServer for triggering Spark JOB . I have used Apache-Livy in my project. https://livy.apache.org/ 
Also you can refer to the thread :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992802/triggering-spark-jobs-with-rest

Comment: Thanks @bartosz25 and @dassum! We are exploring Livy.